# node Js console inputs format?

Tags: node.js, validation

I am new to NodeJs and I need to validate this input format:

Input Format:

- The first line contains an integer n .
- The second line, contains two strings separated by a space.
- n(first line integer) lines follow, each containing two islands name(A and B) separated by a space .

How can I achieve this?

Here is my code:

```
var readline = require('readline');

var rl = readline.createInterface(process.stdin, process.stdout);
var n = 0;
var pos, des = '';
var arr = [];
rl.question('', function(ans) {   
    n= ans;
    rl.setPrompt('give me pos and des');
    rl.prompt();

    rl.on('line', function(input) {
        let x=input.split(' ');
        pos = x[0];
        des = x[1];
    })

    rl.setPrompt('give me arr');
    rl.prompt();

    for(var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        rl.on('line',function(input){
            arr.push();
        })
    }
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Comment: isn't here a node expert that can answer this simple question/review the code above a suggest why it is not working ? when it reaches the for loop ?